# nextjs - useState and useRef caused unexpected result

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rendering

I am a beginner at learning Nextjs, now I am working on a tiny project, that involves login and a nav bar. I hope the code below tells everything. At the very beginning, I want to get the user token by fetching data from my local backend, then store it in the localStorage, and everthing works fine. I get what I need, and I create several helpers for the component to get the token from localStorage. Follow by the tutorial I can directly read the token and use it for conditional rendering as below:

```js
import { readToken, removeToken } from '@/lib/authenticate';
...
const token = readToken();
// readtoken will return something like 
{iat: 1690891359, userName: "test1", _id: "64c0320797629f3ad3a9acde"}
...
return (
    <Navbar ...
        {token ? 
                ....<>Logout</>....
            : ....<>Login</>
        }
    </Navbar>
)
```

But the problem is, the server doesn't have localStorage, so the server will render Logout part, but the client will render Login part.
Ref (which is from the material):

```js
<Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
     <Nav className="me-auto">
         <Link href="/" passHref legacyBehavior >               
            <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
        </Link>
         {token && <Link href="/vehicles" passHref legacyBehavior><Nav.Link>Vehicles</Nav.Link></Link>}
 </Nav>
 <Nav className="ml-auto">
     {!token && <Link href="/login" passHref legacyBehavior><Nav.Link>Login</Nav.Link></Link>}
     {token && <Nav.Link onClick={logout}>Logout</Nav.Link>}
 </Nav>
```

After that I found the solution, I move the token to the state, instead of directly retrieving it.

```js
    const [ token, setToken ] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        const token = readToken();
        setToken(token)
    }, [])
```

The only problem with this is it doesn't trigger the rendering, I find the desired Navbar, after I refresh the whole page (aka F5).
Moreover, I change it to useRef instead of useState, surprisingly, it works well, every time I login and logout, the Navbar change accordingly.

```js
    let token = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        token.current = readToken();
    })
```

My question is:

1. As far as I know, re-rendering is triggered by any state changes, but i did change the state from null to a certain token by setState, I don't understand why it doesn't re-render.
2. Secondly, as I recall, useRef will only affect the ref itself, nothing's related to the state, I don't understand why the Navbar will change accordingly.
   Any help will be appreciated. If needed, I can paste all my code here.

I tried logging all the stuff, but I have not ideas about the issue. I expect useState inside the useEffect(aka componentDidmount) will get the token, state changes, and Navbar shows accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
    const [ token, setToken ] = useState({ iat: null, userName: null, _id: null })
    useEffect(() => {
        const token = readToken();
        setToken({...token})
    }, [])
```

---

Ref: [Updating Objects in State](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state)